# Javascript/jquery Loading a specific div from another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

im trying to load a specific div from a different webpage.

```
<div id="result">Loading</div>

<script>
        $( "#result" ).load("http://bte.gep.msess.gov.pt/pesquisa_avancada.php #boxinterior" );
        </script>
```

I already tried with jquery and with javascript but its not working properly, as it should. Any ideias? The #boxinterior is the div from the other website.

**EDIT**

its not showing me the div as it should and its giving me a

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://bte.gep.msess.gov.pt/pesquisa_avancada.php. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource

Answer (score 3):

Per your edit, you aren't allowed to client-side load content from other domains for security reasons.

If you want that content injected into your page, you should load it server side and include it with the response.

Comment: I already managed to show the full webpage with <object data="url"></object>. is it possible to just show a div from that object?

Comment: @V.David I believe the issue there is that client-side you would not be allowed to script against the content inside an `object` or `iframe` etc., again for security reasons. The content you are loading would have to provide an API.

Comment: @V.David Are you currently running any server-side logic? You should be able to execute a web request for the resource and then extract the target `div` and inject it in your page. Or set up an end-point on your server that simply passes that resource through (a proxy of sorts) and then the `.load` will be accessing your domain.

Comment: No im not, im using wordpress. But im just trying to make some tests with a normal html file. (Sorry if i said anything stupid, kinda newb)

Comment: @V.David Really all good - everyone is new at some point, and this is an exceptionally common wall. If you're using WordPress, you should be able to use PHP to achieve what I described. You won't be able to do it with pure JavaScript without cooperation from the resource you're trying to consume.

Comment: Alright! I will try to find a solution uising php! If i managed i will answer here!

Comment: @V.David This was the quickest resource I could find: http://htmlparsing.com/php.html. While you could probably brute force what you're trying to do using regular expressions, learning to use a DOM/parsing library would probably serve you well. curl is pretty ubiquitous.